# How to correctly get array of array from Json in Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I have JSON with an array of companies. They have an array of products with descriptions and product names. In Unity, I see everything except descriptions and product names. Is there something wrong with the product class?

[image: json in unity]

I have this JSON:

```
{
"company": [{
    "companyName": "samsung",       
    "products": [
        [{
            "productName": "samusung1",
            "productDescription": "description1"
        }],
        [{
            "productName": "samusung2",
            "productDescription": "description2"
        }],
        [{
            "productName": "samusung3",
            "productDescription": "description3"
        }],
        [{
            "productName": "samusung4",
            "productDescription": "description4"
        }]
    ]
}]
```

}

Class in Unity:

```
public class JsonReader : MonoBehaviour
{
public TextAsset companyJson;
[System.Serializable]
public class Company
{
    public string companyName;
    public Products[] products;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Products
{
    public string productName;
    public string productDescription;
}
[System.Serializable]
public class CompanyList
{
    public Company[] company;
}

public CompanyList companyList = new CompanyList();

void Start()
{
    companyList = JsonUtility.FromJson<CompanyList>(companyJson.text);
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your items e.g.

```json
{
    "productName": "samusung4",
    "productDescription": "description4"
}
```

in your json is for some reason nested in individual arrays

```json
[ 
    {
        "productName": "samusung4",
        "productDescription": "description4"
    }
]
```

In your JSON `products` is not an array of products, but rather an array of arrays of products.

So either your JSON should rather look like

```json
{
"company": [{
    "companyName": "samsung",       
    "products": [
        {
            "productName": "samusung1",
            "productDescription": "description1"
        },
        {
            "productName": "samusung2",
            "productDescription": "description2"
        },
        {
            "productName": "samusung3",
            "productDescription": "description3"
        },
        {
            "productName": "samusung4",
            "productDescription": "description4"
        }
    ]
}]
}
```

Or your class structure needs to look like

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Company
{
    public string companyName;
    public Products[][] products;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Products
{
    public string productName;
    public string productDescription;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class CompanyList
{
    public Company[] company;
}
```

But multidimensional arrays are not supported by the Unity built-in `JsonUtility`. You would need to use a third party library like `Newtonsoft .Net JSON` (there is a [Unity Package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@2.0/manual/index.html) via the package Manager in the newer versions).

---

The first solution (a different JSON) seems to make more sense anyway.